# ANTLR C# No Exception Thrown

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm starting to learn how to use antlr in Visual Studio and I can't get a basic example working!

Here is the grammer I'm using:

```
grammar T;

options {
    language=CSharp3;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
}
@lexer::namespace {CoolTool.CoolProject.Compiler} 
@parser::namespace {CoolTool.CoolProject.Compiler}

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

compileUnit
    : 'a' AFTER
    ;


AFTER
    :    'after'
    ;

WS
    : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n');
```

Here is the C# code to instantiate the lexer and the grammer

```
using System;
using Antlr.Runtime;
namespace CoolTool.CoolProject.Compiler
partial class TParser
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("$$%$%"));
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);

            parser.compileUnit();

            Console.WriteLine("OK");

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I pass to the lexer/parser, I don't get any errors. I'm totally confused why I don't get a NoViableAltException for "$$"?

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: I have no experience with the C# v3 target (or VS, for that matter!), but is Visual Studio perhaps printing what is send to STDERR to a tab you're not looking at? Using ANTLRWorks, I do get errors when I run your grammar through the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the C# generated source swallows generated errors in some situations and you need to query the returned objects to see if an error occurred.

Some errors you even might need to add some extra code to trap.

I had similar problems when using Antlr 2 years ago.

I will check if I can find any old code.

Answer (score 0):

I use antlr3.4, and deal exceptions like this:

```
        ICharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(_expressionString);
        ExpressionLexer lex = new ExpressionLexer(input);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(tokens);
        AstParserRuleReturnScope<CommonTree, CommonToken> r = parser.expression();

        if (lex.HasError)
        {
            throw new ExpressionException(lex.ErrorMessage);
        }
        if (parser.HasError)
        {
            throw new ExpressionException(parser.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

your antlr version a little old, but i think exception maybe same